# Canvas, prevent to lose the progress on resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, responsive-design

I'm working on a simple app just for practice.

[Link to the project, you can test it and you will find the soource in the GitHub's link.](http://www.andreamiotto.net/letsdraw/)

It's a canvas app, here is my problem:

Every time that I resize the window the canvas will resize, but at the same time it will lose all the progress that the user did on it.

I'm looking a way to prevent the losing of the user's work, or a way to save the work and than re-draw it in the new canvas.

Any ideas?

Thank you all. Kisses.

Comment: [comment 1/2]   3 choices : **The recommended one** : save all drawing operations in something like an array and redraw the whole thing on resize. Caveats: you will certainly have to rewrite a bit your code, but this is only for good.  **The easiest one** : create a buffer canvas (`var buffer = canvas.cloneNode(true)`), then on resize,  draw a copy of the main canvas onto the buffer (`bufferCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0)`), resize your main canvas and redraw the buffer to the main one (`ctx.drawImage(buffer, 0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height)`). ...

Comment: [comment 2/2] Caveats : this will stretch your canvas drawings, so you'll loose quality and even create anti-aliasing artifacts. **not recommended solution** : use CSS. Same caveats as the buffer solution + a lot of complications if you do listen to mouse events since canvas matrix has its own coordinate system, and that the CSS will make it completely wrong with your document's one.

Comment: Thankfully, it is easy enough to translate to the correct position on the the canvas even if the sizing is weird. The mouseEvent will give you the coordinate on your screen's resolution, but the relationship is pretty defined. Something like `canvasX = mouseX*canvas.width/canvas.style.width` might work. Basically just scaling the input based on the relative size of the canvas.

Comment: Working [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3ntrLq6t/)

Comment: @TheCrzyMan agreed, but still the image will just be stretched, this will use CSS anti-aliasing + canvas one, and the calculations you are doing here for just a mouse move is what I call a lot of complications (you'll have to do it with whatever needs coordinates in your canvas)

Comment: @Kaiido most definitely true. The method I implemented is downright wrong for some situations. However, I do think that it will fulfill DrwMay 's requirements, without too many negative results. Keeping the canvas size larger than the css size can help a little, but anti-aliasing can be strange if they aren't scaled nicely. So caution is needed for larger project, but I think DrwMay will be fine with whatever solution he/she implements.

Comment: @TheCrzyMan That's why I added the CSS solution to my comments too but OP really have to be careful with it (we've got so much questions because of CSS on canvas in here, that I can't advice using it). e.g, I won't be surprised if in the week-end we see a new question from OP with "Why are my circles not circular ? : https://jsfiddle.net/3ntrLq6t/1/ "

Comment: OP, if you must use CSS, make sure the scaling is the same! Your circles must look like circles!!!!

But really, I agree with @Kaiido , css if you have to, we gave you the method, but the other options are preferred.

Comment: I once wrote a context2D recorder, hack into it if interested : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/b4bfj6uf/

Comment: Thank you guys, I will try to implement the easiest solution, and If I don't like the result I will spend morte time on the first one. It's just a simple project, no commercial use or anything, just for spending some time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the canvas's width/height attributes the same, but change its size using CSS.

Comment: Absolutely not ... the coordinates of the mouse will be all wrong and it would be impossible to draw on it...

Comment: Hah, well it's either that or implement one of the other annoying solutions outlined elsewhere. Pick your poison.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution, even if not perfect

This solution is not totally perfect, but it works mostly the times.
For a better solution you should keep track of the path every time there is a mouse event, saving it in an array an than, you will load it on the new canvas every time the window is resized.

### HTML

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="900" height="500"></canvas>
```

### JavaScript

```js
var $canvas = $("#mainCanvas"); //jquery mainCanvas
var context = $canvas[0].getContext("2d"); //jQuery Context

//function to cloneCanvas
function cloneCanvas(oldCanvas) {
  //create a new canvas
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var contextCopy = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
  //set dimensions
  newCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width;
  newCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;
  //apply the old canvas to the new one
  contextCopy.drawImage(oldCanvas, 0, 0);
  //return the new canvas
  return newCanvas;
}

//Function to resizes canvas on window resizing:
  function respondCanvas(){
  //creating a copy of the main canvas
  var copyMainCanvas = cloneCanvas(document.getElementById("mainCanvas"));
  //naming the parent of the mainCanvas
  var $container = $($canvas.parent());
  //Changnig the size of the canvas
  $canvas.prop('width', $container.width());
  $canvas.prop('height', $container.width() / 2);
  //redrawing the canvas resized with the copy just made
  context.drawImage(copyMainCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```